# Confused about passing a method reference in the Android docs

Tags: android, kotlin

In the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-type-safety#split-navigation) I've seen this:

```
ConversationScreen(
  uiState,
  ::viewModel.pinConversation,  // <--- this line
  onNavigateToParticipantList
)
```

I think that `::viewModel.pinConversation` is intended to pass a reference to `viewModel.pinConversation()`. But isn't the method reference syntax `viewModel::pinConversation` instead of `::viewModel.pinConversation`? Is that a mistake in the docs or did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like an error to me. Theoretically there could be a an extension property named `pinConversation` defined for a receiver of type `()->ViewModel` but that seems very unlikely.